# How to access parameter coefficients using HoltWinters after setting alpha, beta, gamma = TRUE in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a time series, `my.ts`, with positive frequency *P* and I want to apply a Holt's smoother to the data.

```
hw <- HoltWinters(my.ts, alpha = TRUE, beta = TRUE, gamma = FALSE)
```

From this, I get

Holt-Winters exponential smoothing with trend and without seasonal component.

```
Call:
HoltWinters(x = tsPAYNSA, alpha = TRUE, beta = TRUE, gamma = FALSE)

Smoothing parameters:
 alpha: TRUE
 beta : TRUE
 gamma: FALSE

Coefficients:
    [,1]
a 144116
b     -6
```

Am I correct in assuming that, by setting `alpha = TRUE, beta = TRUE` (and leaving `gamma = FALSE`), that R is "optimizing" the values of `alpha` and `beta`? That is, R finds the values of alpha and beta that minimize some form of error? How can I access these parameter estimates, which should be in the range 0 <= parameter <= 1?

Or, do I need to set something like this up instead?

```
s <- seq(0, 1, 0.001)
for(i in s){
    for(j in s){
        hw <- HoltWinters(my.ts, alpha = i, beta = j, gamma = FALSE)
        ### calculate forecast model error ###
        if(currentModelError < prevModelError){
            prevModelError <- currentModelError
            flag <- c(i,j)
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Nevermind! I realized I just needed to omit the inclusion of ` = TRUE` for whichever smoothing parameters I wanted estimated. So, running a Holt's method with no seasonal component would look like: `hw <- HoltWinters(my.ts, gamma = FALSE)`.

Comment: You can just use `Holt()` method.